# I want to process every file inside a folder line by line and get a particular matching string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to process every files inside a folder line by line. I need to check for a particular string and write into an excel sheet. Using my code, if i explicitly give the file name, the code will work. If I try to get all the files, then it throws an IOError. The code which I wrote is as below.
    import os

```
def test_extract_programid():
    folder = 'C://Work//Scripts//CMDC_Analysis//logs'

    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        print filename
        with open(filename, 'r') as fo:
            strings = ("/uri")
            <conditions>
            for line in fo:
                if strings in line:
                    <conditions>
```

I think the error is that the file is already opened when the for loop started but i am not sure. printing the file name prints the file name correctly.

The error shown is `IOError: [Errno 2]` No such file or directory:

Comment: Part of the problem is you don't need to double _forward_ slashes in paths, so need `folder = 'C:/Work/Scripts/CMDC_Analysis/logs'`. The other part is that the filenames returned from `os.listdir()` are not full paths, so you need to add it with `open(os.path.join(folder, filename), 'r'))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your working directory is not the same as `folder`, then you need to give `open` the path the the file as well:

```
with open(folder+'/'+filename, 'r') as fo
```

Alternatively, you can use `glob`

```
import glob 
for filename in glob.glob(folder+'/*'):
    print filename
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't open the path. You should do

```
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    print folder+os.sep()+filename
```